# Timer Schedule run method Every 15th Minute

Tags: java, timer

I would like to run method every 15 minutes for example 0:15,0:30,0:45,1:00,1:15,1:30 etc.

Please let me know where I have
made mistaken below code not working properly?

```
public class MainClass{
    //Set Calendar
    Calendar calendar =  Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE , 15);
    private Timer timer;
    switch(flag) {  //here flag 1 ,2 etc
    case 1: //Initial Server 
    timer.schedule(new MyTask(),0);
    break;
    case:2
    timer.schedule(new MyTask(),calendar.getTime(),Long.valueOf(1)*1000*900);
    break;
    }  
    class MyTask extends TimerTask{
        public void run() {
        //Method Stuff here 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting any exception

Comment: `new MyTask` needs parentheses to work: `new MyTask()`

Comment: `timer.schedule(newMyTask(false)calendar.getTime(),Long.valueOf(1)*1000*900);` I have tried like that even not working ?Is it right my code ?

Comment: remove calendar;  timer.schedule takes tow arguments to do a periodic tasks, the first one is the first delay and the second is the frequency

Comment: Also, remember that you program cannot exit, otherwise the timer will not work. Normally this means having some kind of while loop in your main method to keep the program running.

Comment: A timer could be started as daemon, with Timer timer = new Timer(true),

Comment: When timer schedule initial start server run method executed ,but I need to run every clock 15th minutes example :0:15,0:30,0:45,1:00,1:15.etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following up on your clarification that the task needs to run exactly at the specific minutes of the hour (0, 15, 30, 45), I really recommend that you look into a proper job scheduling library, such as [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/).

On the other hand, if you really want to stick to using Timer, your problem is really to find the correct first running time for your timer, which can then run every 15 min from then on.

You can do it with Joda, as suggested by Ben, but this code will probably work for you:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TimerExample {

    private static Timer timer = new Timer();

    private static Calendar getFirstTime() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        int currentMinute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        if (currentMinute < 45) {
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
        }
        if (currentMinute < 30) {
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        }
        if (currentMinute < 15) {
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
        }
        if (currentMinute >= 45) {
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + 1);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        }

        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        return cal;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Calendar firstTaskTime = getFirstTime();
        System.out.println("Task will start at: " + firstTaskTime.getTime());
        timer.schedule(new MyTask(), firstTaskTime.getTime(), 1000 * 60 * 15);
    }
}

class MyTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("running task");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replied me ,but still run method executed initial server start .

Comment: Thanks,but still initial server start run method executed please let me know ?please look at my post I have updated  ?

Comment: But still initial server start  executed run method ,so best way is either quartz or Joda because I'm beginner please suggest me.Thanks

Comment: If you don't want the task to run immediately just copy/paste the code in my answer. It does exactly what you want. It prints `Task will start at: <time of first run>` but doesn't actually run the task until `<time of first run>`. When is time to run the task it prints `running task`.

Comment: Make sure your timer schedule line looks like this: `timer.schedule(new MyTask(), firstTaskTime.getTime(), 1000 * 60 * 15);`

Comment: Thanks for replied me ,If I want every 1 hour or every quarter do same way or some other easiest way is there  ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainClass {

    private static Timer timer = new Timer();

    public static void main(String...args){
           timer.schedule (new MyTask(),0,1000*60*15);
    }
}

class MyTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    }
```

Cheers,

Comment: timer.schedule(task, delay) could take 3 arguments ( runnable , first exec , delay)

Comment: I had previously commented on your usage of the 2 argument call, which only executed the timer once. You fixed it in the mean time!

Comment: When timer schedule initial start server run method execute ,but I need to every clock 15th minutes example :0:15,0:30,0:45,1:00,1:15.etc .

Comment: in this case use JodaTime lib rary to detect remaining millis

Answer (score 2):

`Timer` is not encouraged, see javadoc:

> Java 5.0 introduced the java.util.concurrent package and one of the
>   concurrency utilities therein is the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor which
>   is a thread pool for repeatedly executing tasks at a given rate or
>   delay. It is effectively a more versatile replacement for the
>   Timer/TimerTask combination, as it allows multiple service threads,
>   accepts various time units, and doesn't require subclassing TimerTask
>   (just implement Runnable). Configuring ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor
>   with one thread makes it equivalent to Timer.

Instead, use **ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor**:

```
 Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(n)
.scheduleAtFixedRate(()->{...}, 0, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
```

Comment: But Still my initial server start run method executed .